# How to create dynamic array in java depending up on input?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

At start ,I am initiating `20` size array fields for taking input (i.e. `std_id`, `name`,...etc) .
I wants to create  a dynamic array for these fields instead intializing length at start.
The dynamic array should be assigned its length as per the input entered by the user.
Please help in the below code.

```
public class Input {
    private int[] std_id = new int[20];// initiating 20 size 
    private String[] name = new String[20];
    private int[] age = new int[20];
    private String[] email = new String[20];;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    private final List<Student> Students = new ArrayList<Student>();

    public Input()
    {
        initInput();
    }

    public void initInput()
    {
         int rec;
         System.out.println("How  many records do u want to enter:");
         rec = in.nextInt();



        for(int i=0 ; i <= rec; i++)
        {
            std_id[i] = in.nextInt();
            name[i] = in.next();
            age[i] = in.nextInt();
            email[i] = in.next();
        }

        for(int i=0; i <= rec ; i++)
        {
            Students.add(new Student(std_id[i],name[i], age[i], email[i]));
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Use Lists or Vectors.

Comment: Use List<String> student = new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: Is it mandatory to use conventional array.?  Check out collections api where you can find many list implementations like Arraylist,Vector etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following lines just after reading the value of `rec` from user:

```
std_id = new int[rec];
name = new String[rec];
age = new int[rec];
email = new String[rec];
```

Following is fully corrected code:

```
public class Input {
    private int[] std_id;// initiating 20 size 
    private String[] name;
    private int[] age;
    private String[] email;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    private final List<Student> Students = new ArrayList<Student>();

    public Input()
    {
        initInput();
    }

    public void initInput()
    {
         int rec;
         System.out.println("How  many records do u want to enter:");
         rec = in.nextInt();

        std_id = new int[rec];
        name = new String[rec];
        age = new int[rec];
        email = new String[rec];

        for(int i=0 ; i < rec; i++)
        {
            std_id[i] = in.nextInt();
            name[i] = in.next();
            age[i] = in.nextInt();
            email[i] = in.next();
        }

        for(int i=0; i < rec ; i++)
        {
            Students.add(new Student(std_id[i],name[i], age[i], email[i]));
        }
    }   
}
```

**Note**: While using loop, don't use `i <= rec` because you are using wrong index and you will get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Use `i < rec` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the arrays after you know the value of rec:

```
int rec;
System.out.println("How  many records do u want to enter:");
rec = in.nextInt();

std_id = new int[rec];
age = new int[rec];
etc.
```

And remove the initialization from the class variables at the top:

```
public class Input {    
    private int[] std_id;
    private String[] name;
    etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the arrays. You don't need them.

Also, if you want `rec` number of records, don't loop from `0` to `<= rec`, because that would be `rec + 1` records, so I changed loop to use `< rec`, which is the common way to do it.

Java naming convention is for field names to start with lowercase letter, so I renamed `Students` to `students`.

```
public class Input {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    private final List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

    public Input()
    {
        initInput();
    }

    public void initInput()
    {
        System.out.println("How  many records do u want to enter:");
        int rec = in.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < rec; i++)
        {
            int std_id = in.nextInt();
            String name = in.next();
            int age = in.nextInt();
            String email = in.next();
            students.add(new Student(std_id, name, age, email));
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One more solution:

```
class Input {
    private Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    private List<Student> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public Input() {
        initInput();
    }

    public void initInput() {
        int rec;
        System.out.println("How  many records do u want to enter:");
        rec = in.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < rec; i++) {
            Student student = new Student();
            student.setId(in.nextInt());
            student.setName(in.next());
            student.setAge(in.nextInt());
            student.setEmail(in.next());
            list.add(student);
        }
        // this line to stop entering data
        in.close();
        // this one just to show the result
        list.forEach(s -> System.out.println("Student ID " + s.getId() + ", name: " + s.getName()));
    }
}
```

Comments:

- Don't need to use array, take List instead!
- In your for loop you need to use '<' not '<=' to prevent extra iteration
- It's quite enough to use one for loop to do everything

Comment: Thanks for the  alternative way . But  i have a doubt for all student objects  the reference will be  student  (i.e. Student class instance) . So basically only the  student's object reference will stored in the list ?? . If i am wrong plz correct me.

Comment: In each iteration of the for loop we create new instance of Student.class `Student student = new Student();`, than we set its fields and add this instance to the list: `list.add(student);`.
So, yes, all instances will be from Student.class and our `list` will contain only students. And we won't miss any users input and will keep all students in the list.